# Changing compose Tables to add new entries?

Tags: linux, configuration, compose-key

My PC is running EndeavourOS Linux with KDE Plasma as the DE.

I have recently discovered the concept of a compose key while skimming through [the colemak website](https://dreymar.colemak.org/). In the [section where it's being introduced](https://dreymar.colemak.org/layers-main.html#sequences) the author mentions:

> You can edit the tables and add pretty much anything though!

While after a bit of searching through the system settings, I have been able to set a key as my compose key, I have yet to find this fabled compose table where I can add anything I'd like for the compose key to translate and web searches have yielded no results so far.

I'd appreciate if anybody could point me to where this file is located, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all very much for the plentiful advice...

Found it out myself.
For future reference in case anyone else has the same issue, check this out:
https://userbase.kde.org/Tutorials/ComposeKey#Optional_Tweaking_of_XCompose_Map

---

In summary, or in case that guide is ever unavailable:

Create the file `~/.XCompose`

Paste this into it:

```
# ~/.XCompose
 # This file defines custom Compose sequences for Unicode characters

# Import default rules from the system Compose file:
 include "/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose"

# To put some stuff onto compose key strokes:
 <Multi_key> <minus> <greater> : "→" U2192 # Compose - >
 <Multi_key> <colon> <parenright> : "☺" U263A   # Compose : )
 <Multi_key> <h> <n> <k> : "hugs and kisses" # Compose h n k
 <Multi_key> <less> < p> : "< p>" # Compose < p
```

Log in and log back out to apply settings, no need to restart.

Based on the provided examples, I trust you can figure out how to add your own entries here.